# Airflow cron expression scheduling incorrect

Tags: cron, airflow

'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 1),
time_zone='Asia/Singapore',

If I want a report to be run every Wednesday (SGT) 00:55 AM, I should put in '55 0 * * 3', but instead I have to put in '55 0 * * 4'. (In that way execution time will as intended, every Wednesday 00:55 SGT)

Similarly, if I want a report to run every month first day 3 AM SGT, I should put in ' schedule_interval = '0 3 1 * *', but then it schedules it to LAST day of month 3 AM SGT.

What is going on?
I understand UTC time is 8 hours earlier, but that still doesn't explain this, because these start 1 day BEFORE their intended start time in SGT.
So for the below (only copied in relevant parts), the DAG runtimes are all Wednesday 00:55 AM SGT.

```
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator

from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
import pendulum


default_args = {
    'owner': 'fs',  # Change to your group name
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'retries': 3,
    'cathup': True,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 1),

    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=30),


# every Wednesday 0:55, so ga_flattening done for BR as well for Sunday
dag = DAG(
    dag_id='SOMETHING',
    default_args=default_args,
    max_active_runs = 10,  # max 10 DAGS running
    schedule_interval= '55 0 * * 4',  #this will be wednesday 00:55 AM, not sure why
    time_zone='Asia/Singapore',
    catchup=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [the docs][1]...

You can specify non-default timezone as part of the DAG args like you are trying. But it may be easier to simplify things, and insert the timezone through the start_date.

The advice suggests adding the timezone information to the `start_date` argument, by building the Python `datetime` with the `pendulum` timezone.

```py
import pendulum

local_tz = pendulum.timezone("Europe/Amsterdam")

default_args=dict(
    start_date=datetime(2016, 1, 1, tzinfo=local_tz),
    owner='Airflow'
)

dag = DAG('my_tz_dag', default_args=default_args)
op = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy', dag=dag)
print(dag.timezone) # <Timezone [Europe/Amsterdam]>
```

[1]: [https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/timezone.html#:~:text=The%20default%20time%20zone%20is%20the%20time%20zone%20defined%20by,e.g.%60%60Europe%2FAmsterdam%60%60](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/timezone.html#:%7E:text=The%20default%20time%20zone%20is%20the%20time%20zone%20defined%20by,e.g.%60%60Europe%2FAmsterdam%60%60)).